# Jquery hide caption when selecting another image - jsFiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/Pctgb/1/

In the fiddle when I click one of the images the caption appears (bottom), and when I click the image again the caption disappears (like expected) HOWEVER if I skip clicking the same image again and actually go ahead and click another image the caption in the old image stays.

Where should I look if I want the caption to be **only** displayed in the expanded image.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your image click handler you can do this:

```
$('.caption').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();          
});
```

Forked: http://jsfiddle.net/DQHgg/

Comment: Yes this did it, completely forgot about .each! Thanks